# PuTTY alternatives to work faster and more efficiently - Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

Using putty as my ssh client for my different servers.

I am far from that level that everything is in the spine which means I quite often need to Google for information on how I perform various actions.

My knowledge is pretty good so I usually know what I want to do and what it means, but to wear it all inside and out of the head will take several years, it is more or less like learning a new language.

As I sit here with putty, I think that there must be smarter alternative to this. **Using putty is a bit like code in notepad, it works but it is certainly nowhere near the most efficient and smartest solution**, so instead I use Aptana etc and can work x5 faster.

Are there any alternatives to putty that can help me to work faster and more efficiently?

*Running **windows** and my servers run mostly **CentOS** and **Debian***

Answer (score 2):

Use a Linux desktop.

Every time I attempt to do something with PuTTY I am utterly frustrated by the constraints imposed on me, both by PuTTY and by Windows. If you have to manage Linux boxes, doing so from a Linux box gives you much more opportunity for better integration. The mouse works as expected, for instance, while it doesn't in Windows. Transferring files is more straightforward. And so on...

Comment: Problem is that am working on Windows and changing to linxus is not an option. Need windows for many other thing's. Dual boot is not either an option, often am doing things on windows and need to do some fix on one of the servers, so closing everything down to reboot to linux would not work. 

So the 2 options left is running it on a Virtual machine or remote connect to a Linux machine and from that remote connect to target machine, not really optimal either.  

Would really wish there was a solution that did not require compromises

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg Get a second machine?  One box running Windows, one box running Linux.  Problem solved.

Comment: @HopelessN00b is a solution but not a good solution, I know about this kind of things but i wanted to know if there is a better solution out there !

Comment: I have a Windows desktop, with a Linux desktop running in VMware Workstation, and Dexpot for Linux-style virtual desktops. So I switch between Windows and Linux desktops with a single mouse gesture or keystroke. It isn't that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Try SuperPutty!  It really depends on what you mean by "help me to work faster and more efficiently." In what sense?

Comment: In every possible way, Like pre setup commands or the function to build and save my own. Think about putty as notepad, then i want something like Aptana

Comment: I use SuperPutty. Then on the various servers I manage I writes various bash scripts which I use to do the common tasks for the server.

Comment: If you're missing IDE-like features such as completion, see [An Introduction to Programmable Completion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) in the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide, and its references. Beyond that, you need to think about scripting (bash or other shells, Perl/Python/Ruby) and some kind of configuration management tool (Puppet, Chef, etc.).